# Regexp Word within a word with a fullstop

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble matching a string with regexp (I'm not that experienced with regexp). I have a string which contains a forward slash after each word and a tag. An example:

`led/O by/O Timothy/PERSON R./PERSON Geithner/PERSON ,/O the/O president/O of/O the/O New/ORGANIZATION`

In those strings, I am only interested in all strings that precede `/PERSON`. Here's the regexp pattern that I came up with:

`(\w)*\/PERSON`

And my code:

```
match = re.findall(r'(\w)*\/PERSON', string)
```

Basically, I am matching any word that comes before `/PERSON`. The output:

```
>>> reg
['Timothy', '', 'Geithner']
```

My problem is that the second match, matched to an empty string as for `R./PERSON`, the dot is not a word character. I changed my regexp to:

```
match = re.findall(r'(\w|.*?)\/PERSON', string)
```

But the match now is:

`['led/O by/O Timothy', ' R.', ' Geithner']`

It is taking everything prior to the first /PERSON which includes `led/O by/O` instead of just matching `Timothy`. Could someone please help me on how to do this matching, while including a full stop as an abbreviation? Or at least, not have an empty string match?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match everything but a space character (`[^ ]*`). You also need the star (`*`) inside the capture:

```
match = re.findall(r'([^ ]*)\/PERSON', string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `(\w|.)` matches "a word character, or any character" (dot matches any character which is why you're getting those spaces).

Escaping this with a backslash will do the trick: `(\w|\.)`

Second, as @Ionut Hulub points out you may want to use `+` instead of `*` to ensure you match *something* but Regular Expressions work on the principle of "leftmost, longest" so it'll always try to match the longest part that it can before the slash.

If you want to match *any* non-whitespace character you can use `\S` instead of `(\w|\.)`, which may actually be what you want.